# linux + firewall + how to check if any port on linux is blocked by the firewall / iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, port

some application on my redhat Linux machine isn't working ( and we suspect that according to application logs some port's are blocked )

so we want to check **all** ports on the OS that are blocked by the **Firewall/iptables**

is it possible to scan/verify all ports ( lets say from **/etc/services** ) on the linux OS and verify ports that are blocked ?

Comment: Why don't you ask the sysadmin which ports are blocked or tell that person to unblock the ports that your application uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just dump the firewall rules your machine runs:

```
sudo iptables -S
```

If you use `firewalld` on RHEL7, you can use

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
```

for a more readable output.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to modify the iptables configuration temporarily to log dropped or rejected packets into /var/log/messages.  This can help you confirm if ports are indeed being blocked.

You may refer to this [guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/?utm_source=feedburner) to enable logging.